# Changing data.table row entries to a corresponding data.table row entries based on whether NA is given‏

Tags: r, data.table, rows

I am quite sure a similar question has been posted but I can't seems to find
it.
Hope that someone can assist me on this

I have two data table for example

```
x1 = data.table(index1 = c(NA,NA,3,4,5))

x2 = data.table(index2 = c(NA,5,NA,NA,5))
```

What I want to do is to create another column in x1 say "index3" that has
the following row values:

If the row value of x1 is not NA, put its row value to "index3"
If it is NA, put index2 row value regardless it is NA or not to "index3"

So in the end, I should have this

```
x1 = data.table(index1 = c(NA,NA,3,4,5),index3 = c(NA,5,3,4,5))
```

I was wondering if there is a data.table related answer to this or a
possibility of giving out a vector
index3 = c(NA,5,3,4,5)
so thatand I can use x1[,"index3":= index3,with=FALSE] to add a new column to x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
> x1[,index3:=ifelse(is.na(index1),x2$index2,index1),]
> x1
   index1 index3
1:     NA     NA
2:     NA      5
3:      3      3
4:      4      4
5:      5      5
```